# Why this overridden method gets called?

Tags: c#, generics, interface, overriding

```
public interface ITimeable     {}
public class TimedDoor : ITimeable  {}

public static class Timer
{
    public static void Add(ITimeable obj)
    {
       Console.Write("Add with parameter - ITimeable"); 
    }

    public static void Add(TimedDoor obj)
    {
       Console.Write("Add with parameter - TimedDoor"); 
    }
}

public class BaseClient<T> where T : ITimeable
{
    public T TimedDoorObject;
    public virtual void Init()
    {
        Timer.Add(TimedDoorObject);
    }
}

public class Client : BaseClient<TimedDoor>
{
    public Client()
    {
        TimedDoorObject = new TimedDoor();
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        Timer.Add(TimedDoorObject);
    }
}
```

In this `Client.Init()` returns `"Add with parameter - TimedDoor"`

But if Client doesn't override Init(),

```
public class Client : BaseClient<TimedDoor>
{
    public Client()
    {
        TimedDoor = new TimedDoor();
    }
}
```

Here, `Client.Init()` returns `"Add with parameter - ITimeable"`

How is this happening? `TimedDoorObject` is same in both cases during run time.

Comment: In C# overload resolution is performed by the compiler given only *the body of the method*; in C# the compiler does not know what type you are going to use to construct the generic. C# generics are *generic*, they are not *templates* as in C++ where a new copy of the template code is analyzed from scratch on every construction.

Comment: It appears you have swapped the strings when you describe, under the code, what the `Init` method returns in the two cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If we add some explicit casts representing what `T` represents at the point `Timer.Add(TimedDoorObject)` is called it makes it more obvious what is happening.

```
public class BaseClient<T> where T : ITimeable
{
    public T TimedDoorObject;
    public virtual void Init()
    {
        Timer.Add((ITimeable)TimedDoorObject);
    }
}

public class Client : BaseClient<TimedDoor>
{
    public Client()
    {
        TimedDoorObject = new TimedDoor();
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        Timer.Add((TimedDoor)TimedDoorObject);
    }
}
```

So when `BaseClient` is complied all it knows is `T` is some kind of `ITimeable` object, so the best overload it is able to link to is the `void Add(ITimeable obj)` version. In contrast at compile time `Client` knows `T` represents a `TimedDoor` so it uses the `void Add(TimedDoor obj)` function because it is a better match than `void Add(ITimeable obj)`.

Answer (score 4):

> TimedDoorObject is same in both cases during run time.

True, but the method is chosen based on what the *parameter* is typed as when called, not the type of the *object* it currently points to. So, for example, this would call the `ITimeable` method even though `td` is a `TimedDoor`:

```
TimeDoor td = new TimedDoor();
Timer.Add((ITimeable)td);
```

Within the context of the base class, the `TimedDoorObject` field is typed as `ITimeable`. The overridden `Init` references the `TimedDoorObject` field of the derived class, which is typed as `TimedDoor`.

Comment: Correct. If he wanted a different behavior where it was the actual runtime type that mattered, and not the compile-time type, he could use `Timer.Add((dynamic)TimedDoorObject);` inside the virtual method. Of course that is slower, because the overload resolution logic will have to run at runtime.